# Upgrading ubuntu 12.04 from 32 to 64 bit

Tags: installation, upgrade, 64-bit, 32-bit

So I know this has been asked alot on this site, but I want to be a 100% sure if I am doing it correct (seeing as I don't want to break my notebook or what not).

I read several questions and I think I figured out how to do it, (please note I only have 32 bit for a day, so I don't have to be afraid of losing files):

1. First I go to Ubuntu.com.
2. Once there I'll download the 64 bit version.
3. I restart my computer and dual-boot to the 64-bit version.
4. Once I am in the 64-bit version I perform steps 3 to 5 of [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/152841) question.

Am I correct? Or will my laptop fall apart if I attempt this?

I did the test described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit), and yes my notebook is 64-bit compatible.

I am totally new with Ubuntu so please be gentle :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really have to uninstall the previous 32 bit version of your Ubuntu. [Download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) the 64 bit image and install it on the same partition where you installed the 32 bit version. That should do it. I followed the same approach when I installed 12.10 on my Desktop and I dint screw it up! And don't forget to format the EXT4 partition so that remnants of  32 bit is completely wiped out.

Comment: I see you're totally right! By the way I also found out that once you start wubi.exe he automatically asks if you want to remove the version already installed :D Now my notebook is monoboot again! I just have to make a bootable usb for now :) thank you!